# Test Suite framework in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle multimodule project structure as below:
**proj---**

```
module1
module2
module3
build.gradle
settings.gradle
```

**TestSuite----**

```
src/test
build.gradle
```

where TestSuite and proj are parallel located
This test suite requires module3 dependencies during build, how can I implement with this structure and what can be the best way to execute this?

I have tried this:

does that mean I need to create one settings.gradle and build.gradle at root level like this:

1. `settings.gradle ----- includeFlat 'proj', 'TESTSUIT'`
2. `build.gradle -------    project(':TestSuit'){ dependencies { compile project(':proj')  } }`

   But this does not resolve dependencies for module3 for TestSuite..Am  I going with wrong approach?

Comment: The project structure is not clear to me. module1, 2, 3 and TestSuite are all subprojects of proj on the same level?

Comment: module 1,2,3 are subprojects of proj and Test suite is a directory parallel to proj with tests.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this as a multiproject build with module1, module2, module3 and TestSuite being subprojects. You would need to explicitly set projectdir for TestSuite in your settings.gradle file. This setup allows you then to declare a compile project dependency in TestSuite

```
...
dependencies{
    compile project(":module3")
}
...
```

Comment: does that mean I need to create one settings.gradle and build.gradle at root level like this:                                               1)settings.gradle ----- includeFlat 'proj', 'TESTSUIT'                        2) build.gradle ------- apply plugin: 'java'

//project(':CCL-JIVE-TESTSUIT') {dependencies{
  compile project(':proj')
}
}